# Condor central manager could not see the other computing nodes

Tags: hpc, condor

I connect three servers to form an HPC cluster using condor as a middleware when I run the command condor_status from the central manager it does not shows the other nodes I can run jobs in the central manager and connect to the other nodes via SSH but it seems that there is something missing in condor configuration files where I set the central manager as condor host and allows writing and reading for everyone. I keep the daemon MASTER, STARTD in the daemon list for the worker nodes.

When I run condor_status in the central manager it just show the central manager and when I run it on the compute node it give me the error "CEDAR:6001:Failed to connect to" followed by the central manager IP and port number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manage to solve it. The problem was in the central manager's firewall (in my case it was iptables) which was running.
So, when I stopped the firewall (su -c "service iptables stop") all nodes appeared normally, typing condor_status".

The firewall status can be checked using "service iptables status".

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be going on here. I'd suggest you follow this tutorial and see if it resolves your problems -

http://spinningmatt.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/getting-started-creating-a-multiple-node-condor-pool/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259

Answer (score 0):

In my case the service "condor.exe" was not running on the server. I had stopped manually. I just start it and every thing went fine.